# How to generate significant level for the following data (Fisher exact)

Tags: chi-squared-test, spss, biostatistics, fishers-exact-test, genetics

I have a categorical data that I don't know how to generate the significant level.

Row = Group A and Group B;
Column = Unchanged, upgrade, downgrade (From left to right)

| 7 | 6 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 0 | 6 |

I tried to run in SPSS but pearson chi square test cannot be used as 4 cells have expected count <5. Fisher exact only limited to 2x2 table. As normal distribution cannot be assumed, how can I proceed with my statistical analysis?

p.s. Want to draw a conclusion that group A has significant more upgrade than group B.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hello Ivan! If you only want to draw a conclusion regarding the upgrade status, why don't you simply merge "unchanged" and "downgrade" together?

Comment: This is because there is implication in the interpretation, that I must separate into 3 groups. Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of implication it has? It might be important to suggest you a relevant solution.

Comment: By the way, it is entirely possible to run a Fisher test on a 3x2 table, you might be just facing a software limitation here. For example, there's no such a limitation in R (on your table, `fisher.test(rbind(c(7,6,4), c(4,0,6)))` outputs a p-value of ~0.07). But Fisher test is not necessarily the best option, depending on why exactly you must separate into 3 groups. That being said, your sample is quite small anyway, so whatever test you run, ultimately it might be difficult to detect a difference between group A and group B.

Comment: I am analysing genetic mutation in a disease, which the disease is divided into 2 groups - (The disease is caused by mutation in genes with definite evidence - Group 1) vs (Mutation in genes without definite evidence - Group 2)

The mutations are reanalyse, in which whether how the classification of the mutation change after reanalysis.
So it would expected that for group 1 disease, after renalysis, there will be upgrade from initial classificaiton; where as in group 2, after renalysis, there will be downgrade from initial classificaiton
(Sorry is a bit complicated, hope I explain it well)

Comment: May I know if 3x2 Fisher test can be done in SPSS?

Comment: I'd suggest to edit your question and add all this information there (instead of in the comment section),  it will make the info more visible and will move the question up the list of questions. This way, you'll be more likely to get answers by other people than me. // As for SPSS, I don't use it, so I have no idea if it offers this feature, but you have other (free) options if it doesn't. Besides R, you can use this online calculator for conducting Fisher's test on 3X2 tables: http://vassarstats.net/fisher2x3.html (there are other online calculators doing that, this is just an example)